# To show that a given probability tends to $0$ in the limit

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_n $ is Binomial $B(n,p)$, $p > 0 $, For fixed $b > 0$, we have $P( X_n \leq b ) \to 0 $

MY attempt: I am trying to show that the following

$$ y_n = P(X_n \leq b ) = \sum_{k=0}^{b} { n \choose k } p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

but, this looks like a rather complicated sequence. Is there way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_{i} = B(1,p)$ then we can write

$X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_{i}$.

Now as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the distribution will be asymptotically normal from the central limit theorem. I think you can take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

As all the terms in the series are guaranteed to be strictly positive we can say

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^b \dbinom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} =  \sum_{k=0}^b p^k \lim_{n\to +\infty}\dbinom{n}{k} (1-p)^{n-k} $$

So you need only prove that for all $k:0\leq k\leq b,$ that $\;\lim_{n\to +\infty} \binom{n}{k} (1-p)^{n-k} = 0\;$ when $\;0<p<1\;$ ?

Comment: When I started, there were no answers. Depending on your background, which you have not shared with us, and whether you know about the CLT, Kemp's suggested approach may be the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard terminology to say $X_n$ is binomial (usually Bernoulli is
only for $n=1$). Your equality
is correct, but perhaps not the best approach (although you might be
able to use Stirling's formula to tame the factorials in the binomial
coefficient).

However, with increasing $n,$ $Bin(n, p)$ approaches normal in
the sense that 
$$P\{X_n \le b\} \rightarrow \Phi((b - np)/\sqrt{np(1-np}) = c_n,$$ 
where $\Phi$ in the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
This is a form of the (DeMoivre-Laplace) Central Limit Theorem.
What happens to $c_n$ with increasing $n$?